# Free Bug tracking software that integrates with Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control, bug-tracking

I was wondering if there were any recommended free bug tracking and or ticketing software that integrates with Subversion.  The only requirements are that the software runs on Windows(SQL Server backend and Windows Server).  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.asitrack.com. It has Subversion integration built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used BugTracker.NET. It [integrates](http://ifdefined.com/doc_bug_tracker_subversion.html) with SVN. It's written using the .net framework, so it's easy to maintain if you're in a .net shop.

Answer (score 9):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) integrates very well with subversion and is great overall. I have it running on 2003 and 2008 server. It can [connect Subversion commits to tickets](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFaq#can-trac-automatically-update-a-ticket-when-i-commit-a-changeset). I found installation to be mildly complicated, because to run it properly you need a combo of Python and Apache 2.0 all properly set up, but it's nothing impossible.

There is a number of other ticketing systems that integrate with Subversion as well. See for example [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/2.16/html/integration.html) and [Mantis](http://alt-tag.com/blog/archives/2006/11/integrating-mantis-and-subversion/), which @Eric Seppanen elaborates on more in his answer.

Comment: Agreed, I use trac for my projects and I like it. It runs on MS Windows, but it is far easier to just use sqlite rather than trying to hook it up with SQL Server, if thats even doable.

Answer (score 3):

Check [Artifacts for Web](http://www.versioned.com/artifacts/web/). It's free, lightweight and requires no server or client installation (uses your Subversion repository).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Mantis](http://www.mantisbt.org/).

It can take a little bit of work to set up all the scripts to connect svn to Mantis, but it can do things like have notes appear in a bug report whenever a checkin mentions that bug#.  You can also cross-link between the svn web interface and the mantis bug pages.

[Some links](http://www.mantisbt.org/blog/?p=4) about interfacing Mantis to source control systems.